# How to do a loop to fill a database table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I just wanted to know how to do a loop and fill a database table with fake data in order to get 500,000 records. I have a table with the following fields, for customer_id we have 1-1000, staff_id we have 1-5 staff, car_id is between 1-10,000, qty is 1-3, date_ordered is from 1975 to 2017, date_returned is from 1975 to 2017, For the dates the difference between date_ordered and date_returned should be between 2-3 days.

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

```
CREATE TABLE car_transaction
(
  transaction_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  customer_id INTEGER,
  staff_id INTEGER,
  car_ID INTEGER,
  QTY INTEGER,
  date_ordered,
  date_returned,
  PRIMARY KEY (transaction_id));
```

Comment: Do you just want random data in the table?

Comment: I do yeah, just test data! Thanks!

Comment: *... how to do ...:* 1) Choose the programming language you'd like to use. 2) Write code to get the job done. 3) If you experience difficulties with 2), come back, post your code and ask your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is totally possible with only pure MySQL SQL code.

This is the table i've used

```
CREATE TABLE car_transaction
(
  transaction_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, # included AUTO_INCREMENT HERE
  customer_id INTEGER,
  staff_id INTEGER,
  car_ID INTEGER,
  QTY INTEGER,
  date_ordered DATE, # made DATE type
  date_returned DATE, # made DATE type
  PRIMARY KEY (transaction_id)
```

);

> for customer_id we have 1-1000, staff_id we have 1-5 staff, car_id is
>   between 1-10,000, qty is 1-3

These fields have clear requirements about there range use can use MySQL rand() function in combination with a formula to generate those ranges this formula is

```
SELECT ROUND((RAND() * (MAX - MIN)) + MIN)
```

So for example for customer id the formula is

```
SELECT ROUND((RAND() * (1000 - 1)) + 1)
```

**first try result**

```
ROUND((RAND() * (1000 - 1)) + 1)  
----------------------------------
                               648
```

**second try result**

```
ROUND((RAND() * (1000 - 1)) + 1)  
----------------------------------
                               486
```

> date_ordered is from 1975 to 2017, date_returned is from 1975 to 2017,
>   For the dates the difference between date_ordered and date_returned
>   should be between 2-3 days.

The date formula is a bit more complex.
But it still uses the `ROUND((RAND() * (MAX - MIN)) + MIN)` formula

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(ROUND((RAND() * (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-12-31') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1975-01-01'))) + UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1975-01-01'))))
```

**first try result**

```
DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(ROUND((RAND() * (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-12-31') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1975-01-01'))) + UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1975-01-01'))))  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2005-08-04
```

**second try result**

```
 DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(ROUND((RAND() * (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-12-31') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1975-01-01'))) + UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1975-01-01'))))  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1998-07-22
```

Now we will generate one record off data to combine all the last steps.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   record.customer_id
 , record.staff_id
 , record.car_id
 , record.qty
 , record.date_ordered
 , record.date_ordered + INTERVAL record.random_day DAY AS date_returned
FROM ( 
  SELECT 
     (SELECT ROUND((RAND() * (1000 - 1)) + 1)) AS customer_id
   , (SELECT ROUND((RAND() * (5 - 1)) + 1)) AS staff_id
   , (SELECT ROUND((RAND() * (10000 - 1)) + 1)) AS car_id
   , (SELECT ROUND((RAND() * (3 - 1)) + 1)) AS qty 
   , (DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR((RAND() * (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-12-31') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1975-01-01'))) + UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1975-01-01')))) ) AS date_ordered
   , (SELECT ROUND((RAND() * (3 - 2)) + 2)) AS random_day
  FROM 
   DUAL
)
 record
```

**first try result**

```
customer_id  staff_id  car_id     qty  date_ordered  date_returned  
-----------  --------  ------  ------  ------------  ---------------
        633         2    5553       3  2011-11-21    2011-11-24
```

**second try result**

```
customer_id  staff_id  car_id     qty  date_ordered  date_returned  
-----------  --------  ------  ------  ------------  ---------------
        300         4    2380       2  2010-08-21    2010-08-23
```

**Procedure**

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    PROCEDURE generate_random_data_car_transaction(IN numberOfRows INT)

    BEGIN
       DECLARE counter INT;
       SET counter = 1;

       WHILE (counter <= numberOfRows) DO
         INSERT INTO 
           car_transaction
         (
             customer_id
           , staff_id
           , car_id
           , qty
           , date_ordered
           , date_returned
         )

         SELECT 
              record.customer_id
            , record.staff_id
            , record.car_id
            , record.qty
            , record.date_ordered
            , record.date_ordered + INTERVAL record.random_day DAY AS date_returned
           FROM ( 
              SELECT 
                (SELECT ROUND((RAND() * (1000 - 1)) + 1)) AS customer_id
              , (SELECT ROUND((RAND() * (5 - 1)) + 1)) AS staff_id
              , (SELECT ROUND((RAND() * (10000 - 1)) + 1)) AS car_id
              , (SELECT ROUND((RAND() * (3 - 1)) + 1)) AS qty 
              , (DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR((RAND() * (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-12-31') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1975-01-01'))) + UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1975-01-01')))) ) AS date_ordered
              , (SELECT ROUND((RAND() * (3 - 2)) + 2)) AS random_day
              FROM 
                DUAL
           )
             record;  

         SET counter = counter + 1;
       END WHILE;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**CALL Procedure**

```
CALL generate_random_data_car_transaction(500000);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM car_transaction
```

**Result**

```
transaction_id  customer_id  staff_id  car_ID     QTY  date_ordered  date_returned  
--------------  -----------  --------  ------  ------  ------------  ---------------
             1          757         2    2621       2  1982-03-10    1982-03-13     
             2          818         1     368       3  1989-06-06    1989-06-08     
             3           47         2    8538       2  2009-09-30    2009-10-02     
             4          670         2    4597       2  2005-03-20    2005-03-22     
             5          216         2    7651       3  2000-10-08    2000-10-10     
             6          502         2    1364       2  1978-03-28    1978-03-30     
             7          204         2    1910       2  2009-03-17    2009-03-20     
             8          398         2    3934       1  2013-07-02    2013-07-04     
             9          474         1    9286       2  1991-08-06    1991-08-09     
            10          976         1     724       2  2000-05-09    2000-05-12     
...
...
...
        499990           20         5    6595       2  1990-05-01    1990-05-03     
        499991          839         1    7315       2  1989-12-05    1989-12-07     
        499992           14         3    1274       2  1987-11-12    1987-11-14     
        499993          539         2    5422       1  1994-06-24    1994-06-26     
        499994          728         5    7441       3  2000-05-12    2000-05-15     
        499995          512         3    4039       2  1978-02-03    1978-02-06     
        499996          732         5    2599       2  1990-01-11    1990-01-14     
        499997          304         5    6098       2  2011-11-25    2011-11-27     
        499998          818         2    8196       2  1984-01-14    1984-01-16     
        499999          617         5    8160       2  2016-03-15    2016-03-18     
        500000          864         3    7837       2  1980-01-13    1980-01-15
```

Answer (score 0):

If this were my project I'd look around the intertoobz for a software package or web app capable of generating random test data.

I'd get that to give me a CSV file full of data for all columns except the first.

I'd change the table definition to make the first column autoincrement.

Then I'd use

```
   LOAD DATA INFILE filename INTO car_transaction 
   COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'  /* or maybe just '\n' */
   (customer_id, staff_id, car_ID, QTY, date_ordered, date_returned)
```

to slurp the data from the file (called `filename`) into the table.